# How to build .Net Core 5 project with Language Version 'preview' using Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-pipelines

I have a .Net Core DLL project which builds in Visual Studio 2019 Preview but when I try to build using an Azure Pipeline, I receive a long list of errors related to new language in the preview SDK.

### Here is part of the csproject file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
    <NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>
    WarningsAsErrors>NU1605;CS8600;CS8601;CS8602;CS8603;CS8604;CS8610;CS8613;CS8614;CS8618;CS8619;CS8625;CS8629;CS8714</WarningsAsErrors>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

### Here is the Azure Pipeline yml:

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .Net Core SDK'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '5.0.100-preview.4.20258.7'

- task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
  displayName: 'Authenticate'

- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'Build Project'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Pack Project'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'off'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Push Nuget Package'
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: 'my feed key'
```

### Here are the errors:

```
Starting: dotnet build Release
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.164.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
...
Welcome to .NET 5.0!
---------------------
SDK Version: 5.0.100-preview.4.20258.7
...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.0-preview-20220-01+80e487bff for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
...
Barcodes/AztecCode.cs(1007,19): error CS1002: ; expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/AztecCode.cs(1007,23): error CS1002: ; expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
ZPLProcessor/ZPLProcessor.cs(102,102): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/AztecCode.cs(1007,23): error CS1513: } expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
ZPLProcessor/ZPLProcessor.cs(102,103): error CS1526: A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/AztecCode.cs(1007,26): error CS1002: ; expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/AztecCode.cs(1007,26): error CS1513: } expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/AztecCode.cs(1009,13): error CS1002: ; expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/AztecCode.cs(1009,13): error CS1513: } expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/AztecCode.cs(1012,5): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/AztecCode.cs(1014,2): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/AztecCode.cs(1015,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code93.cs(62,41): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code93.cs(62,41): error CS1026: ) expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code93.cs(62,41): error CS1526: A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code93.cs(62,44): error CS1002: ; expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code93.cs(62,44): error CS1513: } expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code93.cs(62,49): error CS1002: ; expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code93.cs(62,49): error CS1513: } expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code93.cs(62,54): error CS1002: ; expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code93.cs(62,54): error CS1513: } expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Element.cs(160,81): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code128.cs(41,41): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code128.cs(41,41): error CS1026: ) expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code128.cs(41,41): error CS1526: A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code128.cs(41,44): error CS1002: ; expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code128.cs(41,44): error CS1513: } expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code128.cs(41,49): error CS1002: ; expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code128.cs(41,49): error CS1513: } expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code128.cs(41,54): error CS1002: ; expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
Barcodes/Code128.cs(41,54): error CS1513: } expected [/home/vsts/work/1/s/CompanyName.OS.Documents/CompanyName.OS.Documents.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    80 Error(s)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Why does this build in VS but the Azure Pipeline says there are errors?

---

### EDIT 1

Here is a bit of the code causing the errors:
Initializing bars using new language here is the issue

```
public static IReadOnlyList<byte> GetBars(string data)
{
    // this initialization causes an error
    List<byte> bars = new (((data.Length + 8) * 6) + 1);
    ...
}
```

return new (67, 1); in the function GetRSEncoder(int codewordSize) is the issue.

```
internal class RSEncoder<T> where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    public RSEncoder(int primePoly, int initialExponent)
    {
        ...
    }
}

private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, RSEncoder<short>> RSEncoders = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, RSEncoder<short>>();
private static RSEncoder<short> GetRSEncoder(int codewordSize)
{
    return RSEncoders.GetOrAdd(codewordSize, (size) =>
    {
        switch (size)
        {
            case 6:
                return new (67, 1);

            case 8:
                return new (301, 1);

            case 10:
                return new (1033, 1);

            case 12:
                return new (4201, 1);

            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid codeword size");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce same issue on my side. Please try steps below for a quick trouble-shooting: 1. Build the same project locally using dotnet build command in command-line(cmd.exe or what), what's the result? 2. Use `dotnet --info` command locally to check the local environment, make sure you use same sdk version in pipeline(Your display name is `Install .Net Core 5 Preview 2`, so I assume your local machine uses preview2 instead of preview4?) 3.Also, if your local machine is windows OS, I suggest you can run the pipeline using `windows-latest` before using `ubuntu-latest` to test.

Comment: Also, if convenient could you please share some details about which new feature of the preview language do you use? A minimal sample(deleting the personal data and core code!) to help us reproduce that issue could be much better :-)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I can build locally, no errors/warnings. The Display Name wasn't updated but the version specified is Preview 4 and my local machine is using the latest preview. I tried switching the pool to 'windows-latest' with the same result. I tried switching the build to VSBuild@1 with the same result. I'll update the post with a more specific code example.

Comment: My boss has decided to roll back to the latest non-preview, so this question is now irrelevant for me but may still be useful for someone else

Comment: Maybe adding a `includePreviewVersions: true` as one input of UseDotNet@2 task could help.

Comment: I'm already explicitly specifying a preview version. If I set the version with a wild card such as `version: '5.0.*'` it would grab the latest version. Then adding `includePreviewVersions: true` would cause it to grab the latest preview version.

Comment: I check that again and found the difference between two scenarios. In local machine you're using VS IDE (actually it's msbuild.exe) to build it while you're using cmd task to call dotnet cli to build that.  You can try: 1. In local machine, check if it succeeds if we use dotnet build command 2. In pipeline, check what's the result if we use Visual Studio Build task.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with similar issue. To solve that, in the UseDotNet@2 task please set performMultiLevelLookup flag to true together with windows-latest pipeline setup. Please reffer to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/use-dotnet-v2?view=azure-pipelines